# Sedimentary Basins GIS Database Australia

Tags: data, australia

I'm currently working with a place on Australia and I can't find the a shapefile polygon of the Northwest Australia Sedimentary basins.

Can someone that already works with this current dataset can send me a link to download it?

Comment: For open data (and often any data) I think the best place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Rummaging in the [Geoscience Australia](http://www.ga.gov.au/) website, I came across this:

[**Australian Geological Provinces, 2013.01 edition**](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/search#!c3fac1d5-48c1-624e-e044-00144fdd4fa6)

The above link seems to require Internet Explorer or Edge. For chrome user, a direct link to the file is:
[AustralianGeologicalProvinces_2013_01.zip](https://d28rz98at9flks.cloudfront.net/74371/AustralianGeologicalProvinces_2013_01.zip)

[image]